# Jest: Mock an NPM module method

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I need to test a function where I call another function from an NPM package called 'heartbeats':

index.ts

```
export async function checkUp(app: App, heart, beats: number, iterations: number): Promise<void> {
  // const heart = heartbeats.createHeart(1000, 'checkUp');
  heart.createEvent(beats, { countTo: iterations }, async (count, last) => {
    const secondCheck = await secondCheckStatus();
    if (!secondCheck) {
      app.quit();
    }
  });
}
```

index.test.ts

```
import * as Heartbeats from 'heartbeats';
import { secondCheckStatus } from './utils';

...

jest.mock('./utils', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('./utils'),
  secondCheckStatus: jest.fn(),
}));

const mockSecondCheckStatus = secondCheckStatus as jest.MockedFunction< typeof secondCheckStatus >;

...

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

...

it('should auto kill app after checks', async () => {
  const mockApp = new MockApp() as unknown as jest.Mocked<App>;
  const mockHeart = Heartbeats.heart as unknown as jest.Mock;

  const mockCreateEvent = Heartbeats.heart.createEvent as unknown as jest.MockedFunction<
    typeof Heartbeats.heart.createEvent
  >;
  mockCreateEvent.mockImplementation((beats, iter, cb) => {
    cb(null, null);
  });

  mockSecondCheckStatus.mockResolvedValueOnce(false);
  mockApp.requestSingleInstanceLock.mockReturnValue(true);
  const isRunning = await checkUp(mockApp, mockHeart, 1, 1);
  await main(mockApp);

  expect(mockApp.quit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(isRunning).toBe(false);
});
```

But I always get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined

```
  83 |     typeof Heartbeats.heart.createEvent
  84 |   >;
> 85 |   mockCreateEvent.mockImplementation((beats, iter, cb) => {
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot (still long way for me to work smoothly with Jest)

Comment: Where does `secondCheckStatus` come from?

Comment: I have edited the test file with the ```secondCheckStatus``` reference

Comment: I have added ```const mockSecondCheckStatus = secondCheckStatus as jest.MockedFunction< typeof secondCheckStatus >;``` to the test file, I forgot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `checkUp` function accepts `app` and `heart` as its parameters, you can create mock objects that match these parameter types or interfaces.

Only the `secondCheckStatus` function is imported by the `import` keyword, you have to use `jest.mock()` method to mock it.

For handling the TS type issue for mocked object/function, you can use [mocked(item: T, deep = false)](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/test-helpers/#mockedtitem-t-deep--false) helper function of `ts-jest`.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { secondCheckStatus } from './utils';

export async function checkUp(app, heart, beats: number, iterations: number): Promise<void> {
  heart.createEvent(beats, { countTo: iterations }, async (count, last) => {
    const secondCheck = await secondCheckStatus();
    if (!secondCheck) {
      app.quit();
    }
  });
}
```

`util.ts`:

```
export async function secondCheckStatus() {
  return true;
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { checkUp } from './';
import { secondCheckStatus } from './utils';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('./utils', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('./utils') as object),
  secondCheckStatus: jest.fn(),
}));

const mockSecondCheckStatus = mocked(secondCheckStatus);

describe('69720608', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const mockApp = {
      quit: jest.fn(),
    };
    const mockHeart = {
      createEvent: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (beats, options, callback) => {
        await callback();
      }),
    };
    await checkUp(mockApp, mockHeart, 1, 1);
    expect(mockSecondCheckStatus).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockApp.quit).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69720608/index.test.ts (13.424 s)
  69720608
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   88.89 |       50 |      75 |    87.5 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 6                 
 utils.ts |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.478 s
```